# Make admins not kick each other

Tags: discord, discord.js

Making a kick command.
I am trying to make a command so that the admins cannot kick each other.

```js
if(message.author.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBER', 'ADMINISTRATOR') && message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBER', 'ADMINISTRATOR'))
    return ('You cant kick another admin!')
```

But I get an error.

> TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function

Comment: Please provide the error message that you are getting as well.

Comment: `TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function `
Ediited it in the main question too.

Comment: I'm not really familair with `discord.js`. However from the documentation it says that author is of the `user` type wich does not have a `hasPermission()` function. It seem to be a function of `GuildMember` type.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are trying to use `message.author.hasPermission('permission')`. The property `author` of the message object is a `User`, which is a Discord user. You need to reference the `GuildMember`, using `message.member.hasPermission('permission')`.

Also, it looks like you are trying to compare the same person (`message.author` and `message.member` are the same person, only one is a `User` and the other is a `GuildMember`). You need to compare `message.member.hasPermission()` with `otherMember.hasPermission()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want an admin to kick other admins then you should check like

```
if(user.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {  return message.channel.send("msg here"); }
```

assuming you have "user" defined if not then you can do

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

if you have that defined then you can check for the user using

```
if(!user) { return message.channel.send("member not found") }
```

and if you want to add a reason then you can do

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ')
if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS") { return message.channel.send("You do not have permission to kick members") }
if(!user) { return message.channel.send("member not found") }
if(!reason) { return reason = "No reason supplied" }
if(user.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) { return message.channel.send("You cannot kick that member") }
if(user.id = message.author.id) { return message.channel.send("you should not kick yourself")

message.mentions.users(user).kick()
message.mentions.users(user).send("You were kicked from " + message.guild + ", Reason: " + reason)

message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} Kicked ${user}#{user.discriminator}`)
```

this is assuming that you have "message" defined and "args" defined but this is a quick example of how you could stop admins from kicking each other if you use "Discord.JS V12" it will work perfectly